# Problema cargar datos en C

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un algoritmo que me pida datos en una función y luego mostrarlo desde el `main`, pero el `dni` siempre da 0. No entiendo el problema.
Aquí dejo el código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define RENGLONES printf("\n");

void cargarDatos(char nombre[50], char apellido[50], int dni);
void mostrarDatos(char nombre[50], char apellido[50], int dni);


int main() {
    char nombre[50], apellido[50];
    int dni;
    printf("Bienvenido al Bingo!");
    RENGLONES;
    cargarDatos(nombre, apellido, dni);
    printf("%s %s %d", nombre, apellido, dni);

    //mostrarDatos(nombre, apellido, DNI);
    return 0;
}



void cargarDatos(char nombre[50], char apellido[50], int dni){

    printf("Ingrese su nombre: ");
    gets(nombre);

    printf("Ingrese su apellido: ");
    gets(apellido);

    printf("Por ultimo, su DNI: ");
    scanf("%d", &dni);
}
```

Al ingresar el `dni` en el algoritmo, el dato que muestra en el `main` es "0", pero el nombre y el apellido lo muestra tal cual ingresa el usuario, No entiendo porque.

Comment: Nunca uses la función `gets`, es peligrosa, ya que puede provocar un desbordamiento de búfer. Te recomiendo usar la función [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/).

Answer (score 4):

Tu problema está en la forma como has definido tu función `cargarDatos( )`

```
void cargarDatos( char nombre[50], char apellido[50], int dni )
```

Observa que el argumento `dni` es recibido **por copia**; es decir, se crea una copia **local a la función** del valor recibido.

Luego, haces

```
scanf( "%d", &dni );
```

Con lo cual estás modificando el valor **local a la función**. Y dicho valor nunca sale de ahí.

Simplemente, define ese argumento **como puntero**:

```
void cargarDatos( char nombre[50], char apellido[50], int *dni ) {
    ...
    scanf( "%d", dni ); /* <-- dni YA ES un puntero, no hay que obtener su dirección. */
};
```

Y llama a tu función `cargarDatos( )` acorde a su nueva declaración:

```
cargarDatos( nombre, apellido, &dni );
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si te ha servido deberias marcar la respuesta como correcta.